# Make simple databinding with rivetsjs

Tags: javascript, data-binding, rivets.js

can someone help me making

```
<div id="infoview">
          Infos <span data-text="appel:ref"></span>
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
var appel = {
    adresse: "Plateau Rue du Commerce",
    ref: "helo"
};
rivets.bind($('#infoview'), {appel: appel});
```

I used the last minified version of rivets.js
Thanks, here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdjaman/DLh3F/)

Answer (score 0):

There what i done, for any people having same issue (i don't think there will be)

```
<div id="infoview">
          Infos <span rv-text="appel.ref"></span>
</div>
```

And javacsript:

```
var appel = {
    adresse: "Plateau Rue du Commerce",
    ref: "helo"
};
rivets.bind($('#infoview'), {appel: appel});
```

Mixed data-text and rv-text, so the proper way is rv-text.
And beware of keypath appel.ref and appel:ref, if you want to use appel:ref you need to create an adaptater